Android app link not working in android some device. It always opening in browser
Some of device app linking working fine. Its open direct app but some of device open browser instead app. Default link not showing in settings -> app. Can anyone help here?
Here is menifest file
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">         <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />         <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />         <data android:host="web.orgbeat.com"/>         <data android:scheme="https"/> </intent-filter>
Here is Assetlinks file
[{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "android_app",
    "package_name": "<Your App’s package name>",
    "sha256_cert_fingerprints":
    ["<Your App’s SHA256 finger print>"]
  }
}]


Not all browsers support app links by default. What browser are you using?

Its resolved thanks @CommonsWare
Check your https://{domain}/.well-known/assetlinks.json.
Once you hit this URL on the browser it should open the json file on the browser and not download the json file. If it downloads then fix it from the server.

I resolved issue. it was from server side.
Solution:
Check your https://{domain}/.well-known/assetlinks.json.
Once you hit this URL on the browser it should open the json file on the browser and not download the json file. If it downloads then fix it from the server.
